# Rewrite one folder to / .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have ton of links in google, like:

www.domain.com/wpsite/galleries/
www.domain.com/wpsite/hello-world/

How can I with .htaccess file can delete this, WPSITE, if user comes from google?
Need links like this:
www.domain.com/galleries/
www.domain.com/hello-world/

My .htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this line just below the RewriteBase line.

```
RewriteRule ^wpsite/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Keep in mind that it will not immediately delete all old entries from search engines. However since rule is using `R=301` it will eventually make search engines remove old entries from their cache.